# Play stereo video side by side with VrVideoView

Tags: android, google-cardboard, virtual-reality

How i understood VrVideoView can play only side over under video. https://developers.google.com/vr/android/reference/com/google/vr/sdk/widgets/video/VrVideoView.Options

How to play side by side stereo video in android app ?
What SDK or libraries can help me with it?

Comment: No valid question, but start here I guess https://developers.google.com/vr/android/samples/vrview Google a bit more next time.

Comment: @RaymonddelaCroix, i read this article. But it don't helped me. How you see in this article recommended to use for video VrVideoView. But VrVideoView don't allow to play stereo video side by side. It can play only video side over under video.